# Junit Testing: Failed to test TransactionStatus

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

Am new to Junit Testing..I have a scenario ,

```
@Service
public class MainWorkerClass {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("txnManager")
    private HibernateTransactionManager txnManager;

    public void task() {
    .....
    TransactionStatus txnStatus = txnManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW));
    .....
    }

}
```

My junit class failing at, getTransaction() where logger.isDebugEnabled() throws NPE.
So I did alternate like below,

```
public class JnuitTestTxnMgr  implements PlatformTransactionManager{
    @Override
    public void commit(TransactionStatus arg0) throws TransactionException {}
    @Override
    public TransactionStatus getTransaction(TransactionDefinition arg0) throws TransactionException {
    return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void rollback(TransactionStatus arg0) throws TransactionException {}

}
```

and my junit class is like,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {DBConfig.class})
public class MainWorkerClassTest {
    @Mock
    JnuitTestTxnMgr jnuitTransactionManagerOTP = new JnuitTestTxnMgr();
    @InjectMocks
    MainWorkerClass worker = new MainWorkerClass();
    @Test
    public void testTask() throws Exception{
    worker.task();
    }
```

But fortunately, injected mock object is of type JnuitTestTxnMgr and the class to be tested has HibernateTransactionManager which is not accepted one.
Is there any workaround for my alternative solution or any solution there to test my original class.

Note I cannot change my jars, am using spring4 & hibernate4

Comment: Thats why you want to use interfaces as type of the autowired fields and not the implementations, so that you will be able to easily mock them.

Comment: Thanks,Yeah by autowiring the interfaces, its working fine. But Is there any other way for this scenario.? since I dont want to make modifications in my service class now.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use PowerMockRunner instead of SpringRunner.
 and use @PrepareForTest({MainWorkerClass.class}) at top of the class

2.@Mock
HibernateTransactionManager txnManager. Don't create new object.

3.Use 
DefaultTransactionDefinition mockobj= PowerMockito.mock(DefaultTransactionDefinition.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(DefaultTransactionDefinition.class).withArguments(Mockito.any()).thenReturn(mockobj);
TransactionStatus mockstat=Mockito.mock(TransactionStatus.class);

4.Put @InjectMocks at top then use @Mock for other objects.

5.Mockito.when(txnManager.getTransaction(mockobj)).thenReturn(mockstat);

Use this all in your junit.It should run.

Comment: After trying all whatever you have told, Getting Exception as I said earlier,
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:340)

Comment: Spring is complicated enough by itself. In that sense: the spring people have good reasons to put up their own runner. That runner is designed to enable unit testing with Spring. Your recommendation to use PowerMock instead goes into the completely wrong direction!

Answer (score 0):

Thing is:

```
@Mock
JnuitTestTxnMgr jnuitTransactionManagerOTP; // = new JnuitTestTxnMgr();
```

and

```
@InjectMocks
MainWorkerClass worker; // = new MainWorkerClass();
```

**only** work:

- when you are using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) or
- when using another you are calling `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`

( see the official [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html) )

In other words: your problem is that you are using the Spring runner, which doesn't initialize the mock objects.

Beyond that: using the @Mock annotation correctly means that you do **not** need to assign a value to the variable. To the contrary. You *either* mock an object, or you assign something to it! Same for @InjectMocks!